# How do I identify the most recent year in a multidimensional Array and use it to access the elements within that one Array only, in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

Thanks in advance. I am working on a small Codeigniter Application in which I am trying to get the latest Donation from a multidimensional Array. The following is a partial var_dump of the array:

```
 <?php

  array (size=8)
  0 =>
    array (size=19)
      'id' => string '36' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2013-01-09 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'year' => string '2008' (length=4)
      'acc_no' => string '550120' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Johanson' (length=4)
      'bbf' => string '' (length=0)
      'jan_amount' => string '50' (length=0)
      'feb_amount' => string '100' (length=0)
      'mar_amount' => string '' (length=0)
      'apr_amount' => string '60' (length=2)

  1 =>
    array (size=19)
      'id' => string '43' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2013-01-09 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'year' => string '2009' (length=4)
      'acc_no' => string '550120' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Johanson' (length=4)
      'bbf' => string '90' (length=2)
      'jan_amount' => string '' (length=0)
      'feb_amount' => string '120' (length=0)
      'mar_amount' => string '' (length=0)
      'apr_amount' => string '140' (length=3)

  2 =>
    array (size=19)
      'id' => string '51' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2013-01-09 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'year' => string '2010' (length=4)
      'acc_no' => string '550120' (length=6)
      'name' => string 'Johanson' (length=4)
      'bbf' => string '' (length=0)
      'jan_amount' => string '' (length=0)
      'feb_amount' => string '250' (length=0)
      'mar_amount' => string '' (length=0)
      'apr_amount' => string '30' (length=0)


?>
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO:

I want to identify the latest year (in the example 2010 - as the biggest number, in the 3rd Array) and once I do so, create variables for all the elements in the array. I want to then use the variables down the page. So when another year is added to the database, the system should pick that year if it's the most current.

What I have done so far:
I have successfully done this sort of thing on a one-dimensional array so I am tripping on this one! I have successfully used the inbuilt `in_array`function to find stuff inside arrays as well as max() to get the highest numbers from their access the other elements. I also thought of using sort from low to high and then use the end() function but I am unable to do so on a multidimensional array like this.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: _So when another year is added to the database_ So do it in the database: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM table)` or similar

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to get the array would be:

```
$index = null;
$year = 0;
foreach( $data as $key => $row ){
    if( $row['year'] > $year){
       $index = $key;
    } 
    $year = $row['year'];
}

// to extract variables from their array containers, you can use the function 'extract', note however, that whenever you use extract, it will try to overwrite the previously declared variable's name!!

extract($data[$index]);

// now you can use $year
echo "the latest year is " . $year;
```